# Display due dates of not standard task list in Google Calendar

Tags: api, integration, task, google-calendar-api

Google released a new, easy to use Task API that lets you add tasks to separate lists and set due dates on the tasks. There is also an integration with Google Calendar to show the tasks, as you can see [here](http://gmailblog.blogspot.com/2009/05/tasks-now-in-calendar-too.html) .

In my usecase, I've created a new task list **"foo"** and added some tasks with due dates. Is it possible to display the tasks of the "foo" list in Google Calendar as well? There, only the ones of the default task list are shown/listed.

What I'd like to have is a new calendar showing on the left in Google Calendar below the already existing "Task" calendar - something like "Tasks 'foo'", that holds all the tasks with due dates from the "foo" task list.

Answer (score 0):

You can switch the current tasks list using the righmost button in the tasks interface in google calendar.

It should update the tasks shown on your calendar.

This doesn't seems currently possible to show more than 1 tasks list at a time on the calendar interface.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! I found the button to switch the current tasks list. It turned out, that this button is not really visible on Firefox >= 3.6 - the buttons are rendered on the next line.